# How would I go about sending MIPI data via Bluetooth to a computer?

Tags: image, bluetooth, nordic-semi

I have a project whose end-goal is to send images via Bluetooth to any device that will accept it. I have been given a Bluetooth IC to work with, and have picked out an image sensor because of it's physical size (datasheets linked below).

[BT Module Datasheet MDBT40](https://www.raytac.com/download/index.php?index_id=29)

[BT IC datasheet nRF51822](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/pdf/nRF51822_PS_v3.4.pdf?cp=6_4_0_0)

[Image Sensor Datasheet MT9M114EBLSTCZ-CR](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mt9m114-d.pdf)

Ideally there is some sort of existing library for the BT IC I'm using that can just take a MIPI input and send it without me having to worry about making it. I don't have any idea of how I would go about finding something like this though, and it's very likely that my approach is completely incorrect. I wasn't able to find any sort of MIPI converter on any sites like Digikey though, which makes me believe that everything is just done directly in software.

If anyone has experience with MIPI or any image sensing stuff at all, input would be appreciated. It's not to late for me to completely restart my project if what I'm doing makes no sense.

I'm currently in the hardware design phase so I haven't actually written any code. I just want to make sure that what I want to do is possible before I design an entire PCB.